# MongoDB nested object collections lookup

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, nested, lookup

I am pretty new to MongoDB (running 3.4) and Node.js and have my difficulties with relative data. I have collections `A`, `B`, `C` where an `A` references some `B`s in an array, and a `B` references some `C`s in an array. Now I am trying to read all `A`s while all contained documents are loaded. Two left joins, so to say. Here is some data example:

Collection A:

```
[{
    _id: 1,
    name: "A one",
    bs: [ 11, 12 ]
},{
    _id: 2,
    name: "A two",
    bs: [ 12 ]
}]
```

Collection B:

```
[{
    _id: 11,
    name: "B one",
    bs: [ 21, 22 ]
},{
    _id: 12,
    name: "B two",
    bs: [ 21 ]
}]
```

Collection C:

```
[{
    _id: 21,
    name: "C one"
},{
    _id: 22,
    name: "C two"
}]
```

My desired outcome is:

```
[{
    _id: 1,
    name: "A one",
    bs: [{
        _id: 11,
        name: "B one",
        bs: [{
            _id: 21,
            name: "C one"
        },{
            _id: 22,
            name: "C two"
        }]
    },{
        _id: 12,
        name: "B two",
        bs: [ {
            _id: 21,
            name: "C one"
        } ]
    }]
},{
    _id: 2,
    name: "A two",
    bs: [ {
        _id: 12,
        name: "B two",
        bs: [ {
            _id: 21,
            name: "C one"
        } ]
    } ]
}]
```

But with my attemp, it does not work. Tried to "join" in some extra field "foundBs" and "foundCs" first.

```
  db.collection('A').aggregate([
    { $lookup:
       {
         from: 'B',
         localField: 'bs',
         foreignField: '_id',
         as: 'foundBs'
       }
    },
    { $lookup:
       {
         from: 'C',
         localField: 'cs',
         foreignField: '_id',
         as: 'foundCs'
       }
    }
    ], function(err, res) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
  });
```

Can you help out?
Besides this problem, would you suggest to use MongoDB for the advantage of rapid prototyping with fast changing content and structure or should one go with good old SQL with such relative data?

Comment: Just want to let you know that I switched to mongoose which allows you to **populate** nested objects easily.